# 500 GB disk, 250 GB free space - Can't partition disk to add data

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, recovery

I have an issue on my Macbook.

I have had a dual boot with Windows (through Bootcamp) and removed this partition later as I didn’t need Windows anymore, I did this through the Bootcamp tool. Though, an error occurred. Now I am missing 250 GB of free space.

Diskutil list shows me `/dev/disk0` to `/dev/disk21`.

Everything after `/dev/disk2` is 500 GB to 10-11 MB (only in recovery mode, is this normal?)

In OS I get this list

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         250.0 GB   disk0s2
                    (free space)                         250.0 GB   -

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +250.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume osx - Data              201.1 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 2.1 GB     disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                1.1 GB     disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume osx                     9.7 GB     disk1s5
   6:              APFS Snapshot com.apple.os.update-... 9.7 GB     disk1s5s1
```

`diskutil cs list` gives me

```
No CoreStorage logical volume groups found
```

`gpt -r show disk0` gives me free space after index2 of 61026166.

```
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2          4         Pri GPT table
          6      76800      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
      76806   61035156      2  GPT part - 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
   61111962   61026166         
  122138128          4         Sec GPT table
  122138132          1         Sec GPT header
```

If I try to partition the disk I get an error about no free space on the disk to create the partition, and when trying to use the disk utility I get error about files.

```
error: doc-id tree: record exists for doc-id 832, file-id 2709173 but no inode references this doc-id
```

Comment: Of what I can remember from my adventures in BootCamp land is that you need to prep the drive again using BootCamp (at least, with a spinning HD, don't know your setup). Start BootCamp, prep the drive as if you want to install windows, than remove it again through BootCamp.

Comment: I have tried this, yet bootcamp will not see the 250gb either 

Comment: Have you tried `diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 0`? Enter the command during a normal boot to macOS.

Comment: No i have not, i have only tried it during recovery mode